# Why i can't access dialog form modal from button in javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, riot.js

Jquery and Bootstrap code is in same page lets say index.html

It's my content

```
 <button id="btncreate" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create</button>
```

I can't access myModal from the button

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btncreate").click(function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work. If you put an alert in the function, does it fire?

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work.  Is there any error in the debugging console?  Does the click handler get executed at all?  What specifically happens when you debug?  Are there duplicated `id` values on the page?

Comment: @Barmar i try alert function before and its worked for me

Comment: i try with alert function its worked, my id its not duplicated @David

Comment: @indodev28: Then what exactly *isn't* working?  Be specific.  "can't access dialog" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: now i can access modal with my button but i should remove $('#myModal').modal('show'); from the function @David

Answer (score 0):

Remove the script you made or at least try to comment it out. Bootstrap already has a javascript library that handles the modal. The script you made is conflicting with it.

https://www.bootply.com/0B9qovFDev

Answer (score 0):

1) a. If you wanna show modal by javascript then you have to fire click event of button by code like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btncreate').trigger('click'); 
});
</script>
```

b. If you are manually clicking the button then no need of javascript/jquery code, `bootstrap` automatically opens the modal.

2) Another way of doing it is using function like:

```
<script>    
function myFunction() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

Call this function on button click:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Create</button>
```

3) Make sure you have bootstrap and jquery files in your page:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- put first the jquery path, otherwise the bootstrap.js won't work-->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Hope it will help!!

Comment: thanks for answer, i try to delete $('#myModal').show(); from function and then and i can access my modal from the button

Comment: You are welcome!! Yes, for bootstrap modal we don't need jquery code, the bootstrap library does everything for us...!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle manually, your code should work if you just apply the JQuery show function.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btncreate").click(function(){
     $('#myModal').show();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i try to delete $('#myModal').show(); from function and then and can access my modal from the button

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work. But try to your Javascript into this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('#myModal').show()
        }) 
    });
</script>
```

you can check it works here http://jsfiddle.net/hvqoa8c3/

Comment: i try your suggestion, i can access my modal when remove             $('#myModal').show() from the function @Adinda